# Accessing XML data within namespaces

Tags: php, xml, xpath

So my XML Looks like this :-

```
<ns0:ASN xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/ASN" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <ns0:CustPackingSlipJour class="entity">
   <ns0:BON_FileNameSeqNum>40</ns0:BON_FileNameSeqNum>
   <ns0:BON_TotalNetAmount>10.00</ns0:BON_TotalNetAmount>
   <ns0:BON_TotalTaxAmount>.00</ns0:BON_TotalTaxAmount>
   <ns0:InvoiceAccount>Acc</ns0:InvoiceAccount>
   <ns0:LanguageId>EN</ns0:LanguageId>
   <ns0:OrderAccount>I</ns0:OrderAccount>
   <ns0:PurchaseOrder>74</ns0:PurchaseOrder>
   <ns0:Qty>13.00</ns0:Qty>
   <ns0:SalesId>00025873_054</ns0:SalesId>
   <ns0:CustPackingSlipTrans class="entity">
    <ns0:BON_LineNetAmount>19.00</ns0:BON_LineNetAmount>
    <ns0:BON_SalesPrice>0.00</ns0:BON_SalesPrice>
    <ns0:DeliveryDate>2016-11-30</ns0:DeliveryDate>
    <ns0:ItemId>25712</ns0:ItemId>
    <ns0:Ordered>1.00</ns0:Ordered>
    <ns0:PackingSlipId>00339_061</ns0:PackingSlipId>
    <ns0:Qty>1.00</ns0:Qty>
   </ns0:CustPackingSlipTrans>
   <ns0:CustPackingSlipTrans class="entity">
    <ns0:BON_LineNetAmount>19.00</ns0:BON_LineNetAmount>
    <ns0:BON_SalesPrice>0.00</ns0:BON_SalesPrice>
    <ns0:DeliveryDate>2-11-30</ns0:DeliveryDate>
    <ns0:ItemId>25823-35714</ns0:ItemId>
    <ns0:Ordered>1.00</ns0:Ordered>
    <ns0:PackingSlipId>00_061</ns0:PackingSlipId>
    <ns0:Qty>1.00</ns0:Qty>
   </ns0:CustPackingSlipTrans>
  </ns0:CustPackingSlipJour>
 </ns0:ASN>
```

How can I access the value of `ItemId` for all `CustPackingSlipTrans` ?

I have tried various ways of getting it, for instance registering `xpath` and then trying to access. However, it ins't working for me. Whats the best way to get it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `DOMXPath::query` method:

```
// $xml contains your xml contents
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("ns0:CustPackingSlipJour/ns0:CustPackingSlipTrans/ns0:ItemId") as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue);
}
```

The output:

```
string(5) "25712"
string(11) "25823-35714"
```

---

[***DEMO***](https://eval.in/728005)

Comment: hi @RomanPerekhrest

Thank you for the answer, it works partially. In the question, I've added the string in the file I use the code. However, the XML would be present in an xml file in the same folder, we have to access that XML file and then get `ColliId` data.

What can we do in this regard?

Comment: Do not rely on the namespace prefixes from the document. Register your own. The prefix can change on any element node and its optional. Additionally use DOMXpath::evaluate() to use all of XPath (query can only return node lists).

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the namespace with the DomXPath:

```
    $xp = new DomXPath ($doc);
    $xp->registerNamespace ('pfx', 'http://pfxuri');
```